# HTML not recognising eventListeners

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener on my JavaScript file to link it to my HTML however, it does not recognise it. Am I doing something wrong because they are in separate text documents. However, it works with my other sections so I think it might be a small mistake that I have not spotted out yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<head>
<title>Outliner</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style">
<script type= "text/javascript" src='setting.js'></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" onclick="reset();" value="Reset form">
  <button id="pr" onclick="reset()"> Clear </button>
  <div id="ul" class="editor" contenteditable="true" draggable="true" ></div>
  </div>
</head>
</body>

const TAB_KEY = 9;
const ENTER_KEY = 13;

let editor = document.querySelector('.editor');

editor.appendChild(document.createElement('li')); // Add initial (for visibility)

window.editor.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  //let ul = e.target;
  //let li = document.createElement('li');
 //ul.appendChild(li);
});

window.editor.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  let code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == TAB_KEY) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let parent = e.target;
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    parent.appendChild(ul);
    moveCursorToEnd(li);
    } else if (code == ENTER_KEY) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop treating it like an actual line feed
    let parent = e.target;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    parent.appendChild(li);
    moveCursorToEnd(li);
  }
});

function moveCursorToEnd(el) {

  el.focus();

  document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);

  document.getSelection().collapseToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out all of your main code and put an `alert` in the event listener to find out what was going on. It turns out it was sending the error `cannot use property addEventListener of undefined` as it did not like `window.editor`.

The solution was to replace `window.editor` with just `editor`.
Try typing in your `contenteditable` div in the snippet below to see how it works when you use `editor` instead. This is probably because you declared the `editor` variable with `let` instead of `var`, which affects the scope of the variable in a different way so it does not become a property of the `window` object.

```js
const TAB_KEY = 9;
const ENTER_KEY = 13;

let editor = document.querySelector('.editor');

editor.appendChild(document.createElement('li')); // Add initial (for visibility)

/*editor.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  //let ul = e.target;
  //let li = document.createElement('li');
 //ul.appendChild(li);
});*/

editor.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  /*let code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == TAB_KEY) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let parent = e.target;
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    parent.appendChild(ul);
    moveCursorToEnd(li);
    } else if (code == ENTER_KEY) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop treating it like an actual line feed
    let parent = e.target;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    parent.appendChild(li);
    moveCursorToEnd(li);
  }*/
  alert("Works");
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" onclick="reset();" value="Reset form">
  <button id="pr" onclick="reset()"> Clear </button>
  <div id="ul" class="editor" contenteditable="true" draggable="true" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was not that the browser could not "recognize" the eventlistener, but rather that it could not recognize what `window.editor` was. Using just `editor` alone worked like a charm. Hope this helped!